Screen Flicker issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I am facing a Ubuntu Screen flicking issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have searched on Google and found a few of them but none of them work, a few work temporarily but I need a permanent solution. Kindly help me out to get rid of this Screen flicker issue.
I have done all Ubuntu apt updates and the firmware also.
I found a few community bug reports from this
Have done the given solution but still have the same problem.
That solution was to edit grub.
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

and I updated the following line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0
i915.enable_dc=0
intel_idle.max_cstate=2"

Then update the following changes using this command:
sudo update-grub



Laptop: Acer Travel Mate p214 52
OS : Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
kernel Version : Linux 6.8.0-41-generic x86_64
dimensions:    1366x768 pixels (361x203 millimeters)
Display Driver details:

description: VGA-compatible controller \
product: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] \
vendor: Intel Corporation \
physical id: 2 \
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 \
logical name: /dev/fb0 \
version: 02 \
width: 64 bits \
clock: 33MHz \
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb \
configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1366,768 \
resources: irq:138 memory:a1000000-a1ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff \




Had the same issue on XPS 13 with Ubuntu 24.04.
The issue is fixed by upgrading to the oem kernel:
sudo apt install linux-oem-24.04
... or you need to wait until the issue is planned to be fixed in "6.8.0-45.45 or later".
Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2062951/comments/70
